# Is there any way to make 'std::cin' in C++ into a 'scan()' function?

Tags: c++

just wondering if it was possible to have a function (like `scan()` or whatever) in C++ do the same thing as the `std::cin` syntax?

```
std::cin >> data; // or
scan(data);
```

Comment: A complete explanation of what you expect to happen will be appreciated

Comment: I just rolled on from JavaScript and I'm learning PHP. So I figured it would be nice to have a function for I/O (`cout` and `cin`) in C++.

Comment: That's nice. But it doesn't explain what you expect to happen. Don't assume everybody who knows C++ also knows Javascript or PHP.

Comment: I would say you shouldn't try to make C++ look similar syntax-wise to other languages you know just because you like the other syntax more. Just use the proper syntax.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: generally, I agree with you. But iostream's abused <<, >> operator is an exception to me. I much better like the function call syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++17, you can use a [*variadic template*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) and a [*fold expression*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) to create a function that takes an arbitrary amount of arguments and generates a `cin >> a >> b >> c >> ...` chain for you:

```
template <typename... Ts>
std::istream& scan(Ts&... xs)
{
    return (std::cin >> ... >> xs);
}
```

Usage:

```
int i;
double j;
scan(i);
scan(i, j);

if (scan(i, j))
   std::cout << "Read " << i << ", " << j << "\n";
else
   std::cout << "Invalid input\n";
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WmisYgSTVaXmfGP0)

Comment: Sorry, an explanation would be nice as I am still a beginner in C++. Thanks

Comment: Added some information, look for articles on variadic templates and fold expressions for learning resources

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: is it possible to do this without fold expressions (fold expressions are not generally available yet.)?

Comment: @geza: yes, you can use the [`for_each_argument` trick with `initializer_list`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2l83JlqkzBk), or use variadic template recursion.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make a function which assigned a value to a paramater you pass based on your input you could do something like this

```
void scan( std::string & input )
{
  std::string newInput;

  cin << newInput;

  input = newInput;

}


std::string myString;

scan( myString );
```

You will be asked to input a string and then your input will be assigned to myString.